# What is the state of the Wasabi wallet - when will it be ready for mainstream mass usage?

Tags: wallet, private-key, wasabi-wallet

The wasabi wallet https://twitter.com/wasabiwallet

Is still under development. Anyone here who can tell about the roadmap? Whats the status currently and when is expected to be ready for mass mainstream usage (when devs are comfortable to have rigorously tested it)?

And who is validating the transactions in the wasabi wallet ?  Is it a SPV concept or full node, or centralized, owned by wasabi company servers?

And is it a HD (hierarchical deterministic) wallet??

Thanks

Comment: This looks like there are at least 3 independent questions here. It would be better to split them up.

Answer (score 2):

Wasabi Wallet is usable right now.

*"When will it be ready for mainstream use"* is a question of opinion / service availability, and those are off-topic here. See [the help centre](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help) for more info.

> And who is validating the transactions in the wasabi wallet ? Is it a SPV concept or full node, or centralized, owned by wasabi company servers?

The Wasabi server validates the blocks. It creates block filters out of them and sends them to the client. From those filters the client can figure out which blocks it is interested in and it downloads those blocks from the Bitcoin P2P network, one block from one peer over new Tor stream. Optionally one can use his own full node for block downloading, but the ultimate source of truth is still the Wasabi server.

> And is (Wasabi) a HD (hierarchical deterministic) wallet??

Yes